# inserting into array using elastic search with javascript api

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I want to add something into array `“tags”:[“red”]` using `JavaScript api` in elastic search, currently, i am doing this as follows:

```
client.update(
"test":{
"index": "test",
"type": "type1",
"id": "1",
"body": {
"script": "ctx._source.tags += tag", 
"params": { "tag": "blue" }
}
})
```

this changes the field `"tags" : ["red"]`  to `"tags" : blue` instead of `["red","blue"]`,

I am getting the expected output via Ubuntu Terminal using `curl -XPUT or curl -XPOST` methods

My node module elastic search version is `2.4.2` elastic search server is `1.3.2`

Please Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElasticSearch script engine **does not** support javascript, Read:[why not javascript](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/scripting/).

To add an item to a `array`, use the `add()` function and not `+=`

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
"script":"ctx._source.tags.add(tag)",
"params":{"tag":"blue"}
}'
```

Comment: This is not working in two cases,1) if tags is integer type or 2) tags does not already exist, i also tried "upsert": {
       "tags": []
   }, but this is not working....please help

Comment: @RajitGarg-if `tags` is `integer`, then you need to use `ctx._source.tags += tag`. If it doesn't exist, it would be ignored. I suggest you to query based on your schema. It would be more helpful for you, if you set up a new question, depicting the schema, if this is not resolved.

Comment: I am doing this for update integer type field

client.update(
    {"index": "test",
    "type": "type1",
    "id": "2201",
    "body":
        {"script" : "ctx._source.counter+=count",
         "params": { "count":50 }
        }
    })   
    
    
Initially my counter = 10, then it should be updated to 60(50+10), but it replaces this from the new one and result is 50,
    
    
    please help